# A.t().mm(self.linear4.weight.t()) ->error: out of range at THTensor.cpp

Tags: python, pytorch, autoencoder

While running the AutoEncoder model in PyTorch, I found a strange error.

My code:

```
model = AutoEncoder(num_items, args.inner_layers, num_items, da=args.num_attention, dropout_rate=args.dropout_rate)

item_vector = self.linear1.weight[:, T.LongTensor(batch_item_index[0].astype(np.int32))]

inner_product = item_vector.t().mm(self.linear4.weight.t())
```

I tried to make the index start from 0 after seeing the explanation that the cause of the batch index was -1 among little similar problems(https://github.com/jwyang/faster-rcnn.pytorch/issues/311), but it did not work.

This is the first time I haven't had a similar question on Stack Overflow, what am I doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 155, in <module>
    main()
  File "run.py", line 151, in main
    train_autoencoder(train_matrix, test_set)
  File "run.py", line 86, in train_autoencoder
    y_pred = model(batch_item_index, place_correlation)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\saenad\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\saenad\model.py", line 58, in forward
    inner_product = item_vector.t().mm(self.linear4.weight.t())
RuntimeError: invalid argument 1: out of range at c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch_1524543037166\work\aten\src\th\generic/THTensor.cpp:454**
```

Comment: what are the `.shape`s of `item_vector` and `self.linear4.weight` ?

Comment: Thank you for answers. item vector shape is (200, 16).
and when i print item_vector , 

tensor(1.00000e-03 *
       [[ 1.6500,  ..., -5.2615],...
        [-1.2557,  ...,   4.1297]])

and i found  " item_vector.t() " occurs error..
but I cannot find the solutions..

Answer (score 0):

I found the item_vector is empty tensor([[]])!
So I added the code to handle an exception if item_vector.Size is 0 with below code.

```
if item_vector.shape == torch.Size([0]): 
   continue
```

<-- it works.

Hope this helps someone with the same error.:)